# Numpy, a 2 rows 1 column file, loadtxt() returns 1row 2 columns

Tags: python, numpy

```
2.765334406984874427e+00
3.309563282821381680e+00
```

The file looks like above: 2 rows, 1 col
numpy.loadtxt() returns

```
[ 2.76533441  3.30956328]
```

Please don't tell me use array.transpose() in this case, I need a real solution. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always use the reshape command. A single column text file loads as a 1D array which in numpy's case is a row vector.

```
>>> a
array([ 2.76533441,  3.30956328])

>>> a[:,None]
array([[ 2.76533441],
       [ 3.30956328]])

>>> b=np.arange(5)[:,None]
>>> b
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>> np.savetxt('something.npz',b)
>>> np.loadtxt('something.npz')
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
>>> np.loadtxt('something.npz').reshape(-1,1) #Another way of doing it
array([[ 0.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.]])
```

You can check this using the number of dimensions.

```
data=np.loadtxt('data.npz')
if data.ndim==1: data=data[:,None]
```

Or

```
np.loadtxt('something.npz',ndmin=2) #Always gives at at least a 2D array.
```

Although its worth pointing out that if you always have a column of data numpy will always load it as a 1D array. This is more of a feature of numpy arrays rather then a bug I believe.

Comment: thanks! So in the future, I have to do a check first to see if the file is 'mistakenly' read as a row vector? How can I do that? @Ophion

Answer (score 2):

If you like, you can use `matrix` to read from string. Let `test.txt` involve the content. Here's a function for your needs:

```
import numpy as np

def my_loadtxt(filename):
    return np.array(np.matrix(open(filename).read().strip().replace('\n', ';')))

a = my_loadtxt('test.txt')
print a
```

It gives column vectors if the input is a column vector. For the row vectors, it gives row vectors.

Comment: I'm trying your solution, looks great. However, in my case it doesn't work.. File "./bp.py", line 13, in my_loadtxt
    return np.array(np.matrix(open(filename).read().replace('\n', ';')))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 254, in __new__
    data = _convert_from_string(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 50, in _convert_from_string
    raise ValueError("Rows not the same size.")
ValueError: Rows not the same size.

Comment: Do you have an extra new line at the end?

Comment: No, I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much! This is the solution that I want. But the previous one wrote a lot. I accepted that first... Forgive me.

Comment: There is nothing to forgive :) You can accept the solution you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the csv module:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

reader = csv.reader( open('file.txt') )
l = list(reader)
a = np.array(l)

a.shape
>>> (2,1)
```

This way, you will get the correct array dimensions irrespective of the number of rows / columns present in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a wrapper for `loadtxt` to do this and is similar to answer from @petrichor, but I think `matrix` can't have a string data format (probably understandably) so and that method doesn't seem to work if you're loading strings (such as column headings).

```
def my_loadtxt(filename, skiprows=0, usecols=None, dtype=None):
    d = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=skiprows, usecols=usecols, dtype=dtype, unpack=True)
    if len(d.shape) == 0:
        d = d.reshape((1, 1))
    elif len(d.shape) == 1:
        d = d.reshape((d.shape[0], 1))
    return d
```